# Click event won't process

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a question page where when you click on the plus at the end of a question the answer appears. I have the answer hidden and try adding class show-text with display of block instead of none and switching the plus button to a minus, however on click it does nothing! any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
const questions2 = document.querySelectorAll(".question")

questions2.forEach(function(info) {
  const btn = info.querySelector(".question-btn")
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    questions2.forEach(function(item) {
      if (item !== info) {
        item.classList.remove("show-text")
      }
    })
    info.classList.toggle("show-text")
  })
})
```

```css
.question-text {
  display: none
}

.show-text .question-text {
  display: block
}

.minus-icon {
  display: none
}

.show-text .minus-icon {
  display: inline
}

.show-text .plus-icon {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<section class="questions">
  <!-- Title -->
  <div class="title">
    <h2 class="heading">Questions</h2>
    <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Questions -->
  <div class="section-center">
    <article class="question">
      <div class="question-title">
        <p>Question here</p>
        
        <button type="button" class="question-btn">
            <span class="plus-icon"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i></span>
            <span class="minus-icon"><i class="far fa-minus-square"></i></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="question-text">
        <p>Answer here</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You may want to check on your HTML... You have a span that isn't getting closed.

Comment: Hi I just fixed it and it still isn't working unfortunately, thanks for noticing though!

Comment: You're still missing a closing span tag (possibly due to edits by others). If you edit the snippet you can see that the syntax highlighting is off.

Comment: The .question-text was an issue with copy and paste! don't know why, JS File is linked properly as works with every other page. Span tag added onto stackoverflow snippet, just added it in VSCode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try letting your button keeps track of which answer it controls with the aria-controls attribute and use the aria-hidden attribute to toggle the display property of the answer.

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question");


questions.forEach(question => {
    const questionBtn = question.querySelector("button");
    const btnControls = questionBtn.getAttribute("aria-controls");
    const answer = document.getElementById(btnControls);
    questionBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if(answer.getAttribute("aria-hidden") == "true") {
          answer.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "false")
        } else {
          answer.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true")
        }
        
    })
})
```

```css
div[aria-hidden="true"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="questions">
  <!-- Title -->
  <div class="title">
    <h2 class="heading">Questions</h2>
    <div class="underline"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Questions -->
  <div class="section-center">
    <article class="question">
      <div class="question-title">
        <p>Question here</p>
        
        <button type="button" class="question-btn" aria-controls="answer1">
            <span class="plus-icon"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i></span>
            <span class="minus-icon"><i class="far fa-minus-square"></i></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      
      <div id="answer1" class="question-text" aria-hidden="true">
        <p>Answer here</p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
```